# How can interface return an unknown type?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a cpp interface class (pure virtual) declare a function that all derived classes must implement.  However because the interface class is trying to be ignorant of implementation details, it doesn't know about the type of the returned object, and would like to delegate that to the derived class.  The specific type of the returned object is handled by the derived class.

```
class UIInterface 
{ 
    // Should not know about QWidget
    // Would like to defer return type until derived class which implements interface
    QWidget *getWindow() = 0;
}

class QUIManager : public UIInterface 
{
    QWidget *getWindow() override {return m_widget;} 
}

class XUIManager : public UIInterface 
{
    XWidget *getWindow() override {return m_widget;} 
}
```

Except `UIInterface` should not know about `QWidget`.  In some future version, the `UIManager` might be an `XUIManager` which returns a different type of window.  If possible, I'd like to avoid returning `std::any` or `void *` followed by casting.

This pattern keeps showing up in my code, so I'm probably doing something wrong.

Edit based on comments:

My code is experimental, so although I'm using Qt as the UI for now, it's conceivable that may change, for example to use an immediate mode package, or in any case to separate the core logic from the UI.  The core logic, may, for example, be accessed from just a console with no UI.  Likewise, I'm using Qt's model/view and database classes.

Some examples:

- The core needs to tell the UI to open and close windows.  I've concluded in most cases that the core does not need to blindly shuffle naked UI pointers, so perhaps this use case is no longer that important.
- The core needs to be able to glue database, model, and view together, without these latter three items knowing about each other, even though all three latter items may be specific to Qt or some other framework, or split up, such as using sqlite3 standalone and delegating model/view to Qt.  For example, core needs to tell database interface to open a sqlite3 file, ask the modelcreator to create a model based on this, then pass model to UIManager to create the view.  In no case does the core need to know specific types, and it would probably suffice to pass pointers around, but this seems like it's not the C++ way these days.
- Although for now the track is C++, at some point the core itself might be implemented in a language better suited to the core algorithmic functions, eg Julia, Common Lisp, etc., which will introduce an impedance mismatch with Qt, so I'm trying my best to ensure the core can blindly call some high level functions while still serving as the central hub for the application.

Comment: How about `QObject`?

Comment: Perhaps an abstract `Window` class, with a concrete implementation that wraps `QWidget`?

Comment: Consider this case `UIInterface* a = new UIManager; auto x = a->getWindow();` What would you expect the type of `x` to be? Please keep in mind, that the information may only be known at runtime.

Comment: Make `UIInterface` a template and derive `class QUIManager : public UIManager<QWidget>`.

Comment: If `XWidget` and `QWidget` don't have a common base class, I don't see much sense in a common interface class for both implementations. But a common template class as suggested by @dxiv might be helpful.
Can you add a use case for your class?

Comment: You should give use some other information about your interface, there could be other option like splitting the creation in a different component of your interface, but it's hard to tell with few informations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options come in my mind, depending what fit better in your project:

1) Use a placeholder for return type:

```
class UIInterface 
{ 
    Widget* getWindow() = 0;
}
```

you can define in other file `using Widget = QWidget`. You can hange the alias or even implement your class `Widget` later and the whole `UIInterface` will not change. In this case you're just hiding the real type to the layout of your class.

2) You shoulde use a template class like

```
template<typename T>
class UIInterface 
{ 
    T* getWindow() = 0;
}
```

BUT there are downsides for No.2: you cannot use anymore `UIInterface` as interface without specifying `T`, and you're actually to state that`QWidget` is the concrete type for `T` in your code.

Since you wrote *"the interface might change in future"* and not "I would create an interface regardless of the concrete widget type" I guess the option that fit you better is No.1

Comment: 1) and 2) can even be mixed: `using Widget = QWidget; using MyInterface = UIInterface<Widget>;`.